# how to solve this problem with i run in pycharm menu show but does not work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I solve this problem with I run in pycharm menu show but does not work?

- step 1: when I press 1 this function add 1 Rikshaw or when I press 2 for the car.
- step 2: now I want to know the result then press 4 to show the record but my function shows nothing

Code:

```
while True:
    print("Press 1 For Rickshaw\n")
    print("Press 2 For Car\n")
    print("Press 3 For Bus\n")
    print("Press 4 To Show The Record\n")
    print("Press 5 To Delete The Record\n")

    amount = 0
    count  = 0
    u_ip = int(input())
if u_ip == 1:
    amount = amount + 100
    count = count + 1


elif u_ip == 2:
    amount = amount + 200
    count = count + 2

elif u_ip == 3:
    amount = amout + 300
    count = count + 3

elif u_ip == 4:
    print("The Total amount",int(amount))
    print("The Total Number of vehicle parked =",int(count))

elif u_ip == 5:
    amount = 0
    count = 0

else:
    print("Invalid Number\n")
```

Comment: Move all your `if-else` inside the while loop. Currently they are outside the loop.

Comment: And you don't need to end every print with `\n`, as Python does that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your code structure is not correct.

1. The `if-elif-else` should be inside the `while` loop.
2. The `amount` and `count` variables should be defined outside of `while` loop because these were set to 0 in every loop (Due to this, your "4 option" showed nothing).
3. I recommend to print only once the usage (Outside of `while` loop.)

**The working code:**

```
# The following variables should be outside of while loop because these are erased in every loop.
amount = 0
count = 0

# Suggested to print the usage only once. Not in every loop.
print("Press 1 For Rickshaw")
print("Press 2 For Car")
print("Press 3 For Bus")
print("Press 4 To Show The Record")
print("Press 5 To Delete The Record")
print("press 6 to exit\n")

while True:

    u_ip = int(input("Please write your option: "))

    # is-elif-else should be inside the while loop!
    if u_ip == 1:
        amount = amount + 100
        count = count + 1

    elif u_ip == 2:
        amount = amount + 200
        count = count + 2

    elif u_ip == 3:
        amount = amount + 300  # Typo issue. It should be "amount"
        count = count + 3

    elif u_ip == 4:
        print("\nThe Total amount: {}".format(int(amount)))
        print("The Total Number of vehicle parked = {}\n".format(int(count)))

    elif u_ip == 5:
        amount = 0
        count = 0

    elif u_ip == 6:
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid Number\n")
```

**Test:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Press 1 For Rickshaw
Press 2 For Car
Press 3 For Bus
Press 4 To Show The Record
Press 5 To Delete The Record
press 6 to exit

Please write your option: 1
Please write your option: 2
Please write your option: 4

The Total amount: 300
The Total Number of vehicle parked = 3

Please write your option: 5
Please write your option: 4

The Total amount: 0
The Total Number of vehicle parked = 0

Please write your option: 3
Please write your option: 4

The Total amount: 300
The Total Number of vehicle parked = 3

Please write your option: 6
```